# Convert LocalDateTime UTC to Europe/Rome gave me wrong result

Tags: java, timezone, java-time, localdate, zoneddatetime

I tried to search for the same problem but didn't find what I'm doing wrong.

I need to convert a UTC LocalDateTime to a Europe/Rome LocalDateTime.
I'm following this approach that I found on SO but I'm having a wrong result:

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2020, 01, 01, 15, 0, 0).atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
System.out.println(zonedDateTime);
ZonedDateTime current = zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault());
System.out.println(current);
System.out.println(current.toLocalDateTime());
```

I'm expecting the "converted time" to be 17:00 but I'm having this result.

```
2020-01-01T15:00Z[UTC]
2020-01-01T16:00+01:00[Europe/Rome]
2020-01-01T16:00
```

Thanks

Comment: Don’t use `01` for month nor for day of month. You may think it looks nice, but you will get an unpleasant surprise when 08 does not work for August and 09 not for September because in Java numbers that begin with 0 are interpreted as [octal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal).

Comment: Don’t use `LocalDateTime` (unless you need it for an API outside your control). Have your datetime objects know their own time zone. Use `ZonedDateTime`, and for UTC even better `OffsetDateTime` with `ZoneOffset.UTC`. It prevents some silly and hard-to-track mistakes.

Comment: [Time zone converter](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html?iso=20200101T150000&p1=1440&p2=215)

Comment: Thanks for your comments! The second one is interesting.
About the first one the 01 is a mistake. This code was only to test, but thank you for saying that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm expecting the "converted time" to be 17:00 but I'm having this result.

I'm not sure why you're expecting that. 16:00 is the correct answer.

Perhaps you missed that this is **in januari**, when mainland europe is on **winter time** which is just 1 hour ahead of UTC.

15:00:00 UTC time on jan 1st means it's +1 hour in Rome. There's no way to get 17:00:00 here. Try this with a summer date, perhaps. That'll get you a 2 hour difference.

There's nothing wrong your code. That is exactly how to do it, which is why it gives you 16:00:00 (as that is the right answer).

Comment: Hi rzwitserloot! Thank you for the answer, you are right!

Comment: Regarding “There's nothing wrong your code”, well, there is nothing wrong with the *result*. But the code does have a couple other problems noted in comments by Ole V.V. regarding [leading zero in a numeric literal being octal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68875061/convert-localdatetime-utc-to-europe-rome-gave-me-wrong-result#comment121722358_68875061), and [inappropriate use of `LocalDateTime` needlessly stripping away vital time zone information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68875061/convert-localdatetime-utc-to-europe-rome-gave-me-wrong-result#comment121722406_68875061).

Comment: Yes, octals shouldn't be used here. For dates specifically, it never matters. You might write `01`, you'd never write `012`. If you try `08` you get a compiler error. There is no 'needless' use of LocalDateTime in OP's question.

Comment: The octal was my mistake but thank you for pointing out for pointing that out